# Given that $Au$ and $Av$ are orthogonal for any pair of orthogonal vectors $u$ and $v$. Prove $A = cP$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$. Given that $Au$ and $Av$ are orthogonal for any pair of orthogonal vectors $u$ and $v$ in $R^n$.

Prove $A = cP$ | $c \in R$ and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. let $(e_i)$ be the usual basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$.
2. Then $\langle Ae_i, Ae_j \rangle =0$ for $i \neq j$.
3. Next verify that $e_i+e_j$ and $e_i-e_j$ are orthogonal for $i \neq j$.
4. It follows that $Ae_i+Ae_j$ and $Ae_i-Ae_j$ are orthogonal for $i \neq j$.
5. Expanding $\langle (Ae_i+Ae_j), ((Ae_i-Ae_j)) \rangle$ show that $\|Ae_i\|=\|Ae_j\|$ for $i \neq j$.
6. Hence $c\equiv \|Ae_i\|$  does not depend on $i$.
7. Now it is easy to verify that $ \langle Au, Av \rangle =c \langle u, v \rangle$ for all $u$ and $v$. [For this write  $u$ and $v$ as linear combinations of $e_i$'s and remember that $\langle Ae_i, Ae_j \rangle =0$ for $i \neq j$].
8. It now follows that $P=\frac A {\sqrt c}$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: How do we verify that $e_i$ + $e_j$ and $e_i$ - $e_j$ are orthogonal?

Comment: $\langle (e_i+e_j), (e_i-e_j) \rangle= \langle e_i, e_i \rangle-\langle e_j, e_j \rangle+\langle e_j, e_i \rangle-\langle e_i, e_j \rangle=1-1=0+0=0$. @CXY

Comment: Using the above I've managed to construct the equation below.
$Ae_i e_i$ - $Ae_j e_j$ + $Ae_j e_i$ - $Ae_i e_j$ = 0
I'm stuck here. How do i proceed?

Comment: That is the definition of orthogonal matrices (transformation).  Take an orthogonal basis $\{B\}$ you could take the canonical so $\{A\{B\}\}$  is another orthogonal basis. $Ae_i$ is the $i^th$ column of $A$ as matrix.

Comment: Here $P$ is orthonormal from answer.

Comment: I haven't studied Linear Algebra in a long time, so I must be missing something. If $P$ is orthogonal, then $\langle Pu, Pu\rangle = \langle u,u \rangle$ right? Using linearity of the scalar in both arguments would show that your choice of $c$ used to scale $A$ is the wrong one?

Comment: @JessicaK I missed a square root in the defiintion of $P$. Thanks for pointing out.